# How to find lambda in R, if other parameters are known

Tags: r, self-study, poisson-distribution

I am solving some problems on Poisson distribution and I have come across a problem where in I need to check the rate (lambda) of a particular thing with a probability of 0.001 (1 in 1000) of p(4).

Specifically, I need to figure out the probability of finding a 1 cookie out of 1000 that has less than 5 raisins. So I need say how many raisins should be present in dough before its mixed to ascertain the above probability.

**How am I suppose to do this in R?**

Here is the actual question at hand (I am interested in the **Q.7a**), and [here](http://www.umass.edu/wsp/resources/poisson/problems.html) is the link with answers, please look at the answers.

> **7.** A batch of cookie dough will be sliced up into 100 cookies and then baked. 400 raisins have been included in the batch of dough, and the dough has been thoroughly mixed so as to randomize the ingredients. What is the chance that, despite these precautions, one or more cookies in the batch will contain no raisins at all?
>
> **7a. How many raisins should be put in the batch of dough to be 99% sure that no cookie comes out with no raisins in it?**

Comment: It is hard to tell what the question is.  Please edit your post to include a *clear* description of what information you have and what you need to find.  If you know how to answer your question but are only asking about how to compute the answer in `R`, then please delete this post and re-ask your question on [SO].

Comment: This question does not need the Poisson distribution for its solution; in fact, that theory only gives an *approximate* solution. For reference, an exact answer to (7) is $$k^{-n} \sum _{i=1}^{k-1} (-1)^{i+k-1} i^n \binom{k}{i}$$ with $k=100$ and $n=400$, giving $0.847695\ldots$. The answer $p\approx 0.01831564$ provided in the link estimates the chance that *one pre-designated cookie* will have no raisins: but that's incorrect. The (approximated) chance that at least one of $100$ *independent* cookies will be raisin free is $1-(1-p)^{100}\approx 0.8425338.$ (The exact answer to 7a is $916$.)

Comment: I am now confused as to why does an Academic website have an unrelated problem to Poisson and certainly makes a mistake in choice of application. Can you help me understand that, Can you also elaborate why your approach is right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(k,n)$ be the chance that one or more cookies in a batch of $k$ cookies with $n$ raisins (well and randomly mixed) in the dough will have no raisins.  Consider the $1/k$ portion of the dough that will end up in the first cookie.  Complete randomness of the mixing means that each of the $n$ raisins will independently have a $1/k$ chance of ending up in that first cookie.  Therefore the distribution of the number of raisins in that cookie is Binomial, with parameters $1/k$ and $n$.  Let

$$p(i, 1/k, n) = k^{-n}\binom{n}{i} (k-1)^{n-i}$$

designate the chance that the cookie gets exactly $i$ raisins ($0 \le i \le n$).

The events $i=0, i=1, \ldots, i=n$ partition all the possibilities, so their probabilities add.  If $i=0$, we have found a cookie with no raisins (and the chance of that happening equals the chance that all $n$ raisins end up in the remaining $1-1/k$ of the dough: $(1-1/k)^n$).  Otherwise, we continue to examine the remaining cookies.  The assumption of completely random mixing means that when the first cookie has $i$ raisins, the remaining $n-i$ raisins are randomly and independently mixed into the remaining $1-1/k$ of the dough, from which $k-1$ cookies will be made.  Consequently, when $k\ge 1$ and $n\ge 0,$

$$f(k,n) = (1-1/k)^n + \sum_{i=1}^n p(i, 1/k, n) f(k-1, n-i).$$

The initial conditions are $f(0,n)=0$ (when there are no cookies, there is no chance for a cookie to have no raisins), $f(1,n)=0$ for $n\ge 1$ (when there is one cookie and one or more raisins, the cookie must have some raisins), and $f(k,0) = 1$ (when there are no raisins and some cookies, at least one cookie will have no raisins).  These uniquely determine the solution, which one can check is

$$f(k,n) = k^{-n} \sum _{i=1}^{k-1} (-1)^{i+k-1} i^n \binom{k}{i}.$$

The value $f(100,400)$ is approximately $0.847695$.  To check this, I ran a simulation of $10^5$ batches of cookie dough using a multinomial random number generator in `R`:

```
#
# Specify the simulation parameters.
#
n.raisins <- 400
n.cookies <- 100
n.iter <- 10^5
#
# Run the simulation.  (Takes about 1 second.)
#
set.seed(17)
sim <- rmultinom(n.iter, n.raisins, rep(1, n.cookies))
#
# Find the proportion of batches with at least one raisin-free cookie.
#
p.hat <- mean(apply(sim, 2, min)==0)
#
# Report the value with its standard error and a Z-statistic for a hypothetical result.
#
p.se <- sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat) / n.iter)
z <- round((0.847695 - p.hat) / p.se, 3)
decimals <- ceiling(-log(p.se, 10)) + 1
cat("Estimated chance is ", round(p.hat, decimals), 
    " (", round(p.se, decimals), "); Z = ", z, "\n", sep="")
```

The output is

> Estimated chance is 0.8496 (0.0011); Z = -1.694

This is not significantly different from the theoretical value, but it is hugely different from [the answer](http://www.umass.edu/wsp/resources/poisson/answer07.html) of "$0.0183$".  The answer's explanation suggests an entirely different interpretation of the question: it estimates the chance that *one designated cookie*, having a Poisson distribution of raisins with a mean of $4$, will have no raisins.  But that's clearly not what the question asks.  In fact, using this approximate answer, we could compute the chance that at least one of $100$ *independent* such cookies has no raisins: it equals $0.8425338$, computed by the `R` expression `1 - (1-dpois(0, 4))^100`.  This is an *adequate* approximation, but even the foregoing simulation can determine it's not completely correct (the Z-value is -6.26, which is highly significant).

---

The answer to (7a) is obtained by finding the smallest $n$ for which $f(100,n)\le 1 - 0.99$. A quick line search finds

$$f(100, 915) = 0.0100976;\quad f(100, 916) = 0.00999707.$$

Therefore the answer is $916$.  Changing `n.raisins` in the simulation to `916` and re-running it gives the output

> Estimated chance is 0.00954 (0.00031)

That corroborates this answer.

The Poisson approximation gives $921$ as the answer:

```
1 - (1-dpois(0, 920:921/100))^100
```

> [1] 0.010053572 0.009954032

Incidentally, this approximation has a simple formula: compute

$$-k \log(1 - 0.99^{1/k})$$

and round it up to the nearest integer.  This in turn will be close to $k\left(\log(k) - \log(1-0.99)\right).$  These useful and simple formulas show where the value of the Poisson approximation lies: it replaces a long complicated sum for the exact answer by a readily-understood, easily-computed value that more clearly shows how the answer behaves in terms of $n$ and $k$.

Comment: That's quite elaborate for an answer. Give me sometime while I try my best to understand.

Comment: Yes: I felt obliged to be very clear and complete because such a wrong answer had been posted on an otherwise credible academic site.